# Using a for loop with .join

Tags: python

I am making a program to make 12 word long phrases using the `bip39` wordlist.

However with the code I wrote I am getting an error I do not know how to fix.

Code:

```
import requests
import random
r = requests.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin/bips/master/bip-0039/english.txt")

def make_seed():
    return "".join([random.choice(r.text.split("\n")) + " "] for i in range(12))

print(make_seed())
```

Output: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Expected output: 12 letter phrase from the wordlist.

I tried turing the `random.choice(r.text.split("\n"))` into a str but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your closing square bracket is in the wrong place. Should be `return "".join([random.choice(r.text.split("\n")) + " " for i in range(12)])`

Comment: Incidentally, rather specifically coding `+ " "` within the comprehension, you can get space separated words more simply by using `" ".join()` with a space between the quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much guys

Comment: `return "".join(random.choice(r.text.split("\n")) + " " for i in range(12))` would do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `join` method requires as its argument an iterable of `str` objects.  Your iterable is of `list` objects.  Try removing the brackets from that line.  I.e.,

```
return "".join(random.choice(r.text.split("\n"))+" " for i in range(12))
```